# noUislider percentages on the base

Tags: javascript, html, nouislider

I've got this design of [noUislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/), I want to, on update, change the percentages based on the handle position.
Can someone please help with this? I've been on it for the last 2 days trying to find a way to read the values into percentages.
I've got a price `initialPrice` which is the max the slider goes. 
What I want is that once the handle is moved, calculate the two percentages based on that `initialPrice` value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDZ9l.png

this is my javascript:

```
    var financialCalculator = document.getElementById('financial_calculator');
    noUiSlider.create(financialCalculator, {
        start: 400000,
        range: {
            'min': [0],
            'max': initialPrice
        },
        connect: [false, true],
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: '\'',
            edit: function (value) {
                return value
            }
        })
    });
    var mortageTotal = document.getElementById('mortage');

    var equityTotal = document.getElementById('equity');

    financialCalculator.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {

    });
```

this is my html:

```
                        <div class="custom-range-financial">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100 position-absolute slider-overlay">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100 slider-elem-wrapper">
                                    <span class=" align-self-center bold text-center white" id="mortage"
                                        style="width: 40%;">
                                        40%</span>
                                    <span class="align-self-center bold text-center white" id="equity"
                                        style="width: 60%;">60%</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="violet-slider" id="financial_calculator">
                                <span class="position-absolute plus">+</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: FYI Java and JavaScript are not the same thing. What you have here is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: yeah, just saw that, sorry

Comment: Also "JavaScript markup" means nothing. Fixed that for you.